# Laravel Form Request validation issues

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm attempting to create a single error response message for array input:

This is my form:

```
    <div class="form-group  col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="client-type">Client Type</label>
                <input type="text" name="client_type[]" class="form-control" value="Panelist" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="commission-percentage">Commission Percentage</label>
                <input type="number" name="commission_percentage[]" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="client-type">Client Type</label>
                <input type="text" name="client_type[]" class="form-control" value="Non Panelist" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="commission-percentage">Commission Percentage</label>
                <input type="number" name="commission_percentage[]" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
public function store(StoreCommissionsList $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->validated();

    dd($attributes);
}
```

And finally my `StoreCommissionsList` form request:

```
public function rules()
{
    $commission = request('commission_percentage');

    $rules = [];

    $rules['role_id'] = 'required';
    $rules['client_type'] = 'required';

    if ( $commission[0] == null && $commission[1] == null ) 
    {
        $rules['commission_percentage'] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'role_id.required' => 'Please select a user role',
        'client_type.required' => 'Please input a client type',
        'commission_percentage.required' => 'Please fill in a percentage commission for each client type',
    ];
}
```

What is happening is: If all the fields in my form are blank, only the `role_id` seems to be passing the validation check in terms of returning the required validation message. The `commission_percentage` is not validated at all and after inputting `role_id`, the form submits meaning the `commission_percentage` validation is overlooked for some reason.

Kindly assist.

**Update**

Here's my implementation using the wildcard (*) dot-notation.

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];

    $rules['role_id'] = 'required';
    $rules['client_type.*'] = 'required';
    $rules['commission_percentage.*'] = 'required';

    return $rules;
}
```

For this, the validation error messages will be duplicated for each array item in the request, in my case, something like this:

```
The commission_percentage.0 field is required. 
The commission_percentage.1 field is required
```

So the earlier implementation in my `rules` was a possible solution for this duplicate issue.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays because if you work with arrays, you'll need a wildcard (*) dot-notation

Comment: Hi @DimitriMostrey .. the wildcard (*) was my first approach. the problem is the validation error messages will be duplicated for each array item in the request, in my case, something like this: `The commission_percentage.0 field is required.
The commission_percentage.1 field is required.`.. so was working on a workaround for this using the method i've shown above in my form request

Comment: The customresponses have to be wildcarded too. Is the `if(cond && cond){}` necessary? It would be interesting to see your fist code with the * approach.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey .. updated my question to showcase the wildcard (*) dot-notation duplicate issue

Comment: I genuinely don't understand the edit made just now by Rob for my question's title. The title he replaced with does not make any sense to my question whatsoever

Comment: What if you change your messages accordingly, for example `'role_id.*.required' => 'Please select a user role'` and don't forget the * notation in role_id as well `$rules['role_id.*'] = 'required';`

Comment: Did that.. in my `rules`: `$rules['commission_percentage.*'] = 'required';` and in my `message` function, `'commission_percentage.*.required' => 'Please fill in a percentage commission for each client type',` but validation error message is still duplicated i.e. `Please fill in a percentage commission for each client type
Please fill in a percentage commission for each client type`